# A SQL query searching for rows that satisfy Column1 <= X <= Column2 is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am using a MySQL DB, and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (
  PrimaryKeyCol BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  A BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  FirstX INT(11) NOT NULL,
  LastX INT(11) NOT NULL,
  P INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Y INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Z INT(11) NOT NULL,
  B BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PrimaryKeyCol),
  UNIQUE KEY FirstLastXPriority_Index (FirstX,LastX,P)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The table contains 4.3 million rows, and never changes once initialized.

The important columns of this table are `FirstX`, `LastX`, `Y`, `Z` and `P`.

As you can see, I have a unique index on the rows `FirstX`, `LastX` and `P`.

The columns `FirstX` and `LastX` define a range of integers.

The query I need to run on this table fetches for a given X all the rows having FirstX <= X <= LastX (i.e. all the rows whose range contains the input number X).

For example, if the table contains the rows (I'm including only the relevant columns):

| FirstX | LastX | P | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000 | 500000 | 1 | 111 | 222 |
| 150000 | 220000 | 2 | 333 | 444 |
| 180000 | 190000 | 3 | 555 | 666 |
| 550000 | 660000 | 4 | 777 | 888 |
| 700000 | 900000 | 5 | 999 | 111 |
| 750000 | 850000 | 6 | 222 | 333 |

and I need, for example, the rows that contain the value `185000`, the first `3` rows should be returned.

The query I tried, which should be using the index, is:

```
SELECT P, Y, Z FROM SomeTable WHERE FirstX <= ? AND LastX >= ? LIMIT 10;
```

Even without the LIMIT, this query should return a small number of records (less than `50`) for any given X.

This query was executed by a Java application for `120000` values of X. To my surprise, it took over **10 hours (!)** and the average time per query was **0.3 seconds**.

This is not acceptable, not even near acceptable. It should be much faster.

I examined a single query that took **0.563 seconds** to make sure the index was being used. The query I tried (the same as the query above with a specific integer value instead of `?`) returned **2 rows**.

I used `EXPLAIN` to find out what was happening:

```
id               1
select_type      SIMPLE
table            SomeTable 
type             range
possible_keys    FirstLastXPriority_Index
key              FirstLastXPriority_Index 
key_len          4
ref              NULL
rows             2104820
Extra            Using index condition
```

As you can see, the execution involved `2104820` rows (nearly 50% of the rows of the table), even though only 2 rows satisfy the conditions, so half of the index is examined in order to return just 2 rows.

Is there something wrong with the query or the index? Can you suggest an improvement to the query or the index?

EDIT:

Some answers suggested that I run the query in batches for multiple values of X. I can't do that, since I run this query in real time, as inputs arrive to my application. Each time an input X arrives, I must execute the query for X and perform some processing on the output of the query.

Comment: If some points on the binary tree are really clogged with entries you may have punishingly slow queries here. I know that bounding tests can scale really badly on certain kinds of data, it's a persistent problem in 3D type applications for things like collision detection, so you may need a better indexing method than the naive one you have here.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the comment. What kind of better indexing method could that be?

Comment: what is the value off the innodb buffer pool?  `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size` should have been by 75 - 80% off your total RAM if the server is dedicated to run on MySQL only

Comment: Since you've dealing with a simple scalar here, a simplified [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) might be the answer, or something like that where you're able to quickly exclude 99% of the rows and focus on the remainder.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I haven't tested it on a dedicated server, only on a development machine. The value of that parameter is `402653184`. If that's the size in bytes, it's quite small compared to my total RAM. Would increasing that value help?

Comment: Is FirstX unique in combination with P? And how about LastX?

Comment: @Clydog FirstX is unique in combination with LastX and P.

Comment: @Eran, yes, I see that, but I'm wondering whether a pair of unique indices could be defined that omitted FirstX and LastX respectively. Obviously this depends on the real data.

Comment: @Clydog I'll have to check the data

Comment: Could you try to create covering index like this: `create index ix_table on sometable(lastx, firstx, p, y, z)`?

Comment: @RadimBača I can, and I just tried it, but it didn't help (and I didn't expect it to).

Comment: @Clydog Why do the pair of indices have to be unique? Would unique indices perform better than non-unique indices? Even if I do find out that the current data allows a pair of unique indices, I have no guarantee that a future version of the table won't have duplicates.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. "This query was executed by a Java application for 120000 values of X." Given this & your select statement it looks like you are submitting all of these Xs *one at a time*? Put them in a (sorted) indexed table then select them all at once. Also read about spatial indexes, because this is the kind of application they are for.

Comment: @philipxy The fact that this query is part of a Java application is just a side note. The issue also happens when I run a single SQL query in mysql workbench. I do submit the queries one at a time, since I process the queries as inputs come into my system in real time: input comes, I run the query, and process the query result. I can't collect the inputs and submit them all at once.

Comment: What are the lower & upper boundaries of X?

Comment: How random are the search parameters? What is their number? Do they take all the values from MIN(FirstX) to MAX(LastX)? Probably it is better to create the second table and store the search parameters and list of search results (`SomeTable.PrimaryKeyCol` or real math result data that we do not know) inside it... Actually the question does not contain the purpose of such a fitering. Can it be an X-Y problem?

Comment: @asd-tm I apologize for not including the purpose of the filtering. I am not allowed to. I don't know the number of unique possible search parameters. They don't take the entire range from MIN(FirstX) to MAX(LastX), but they probably take most of the values in the individual ranges (i.e. the ranges FirstX to LastX for each row of the table).

Comment: @Used_By_Already I can tell you the lower and upper bounds of FirstX and LastX - the values of FirstX are currently in the range `-2147465472 to 2128712320`. The values of `LastX` are currently in the range `-2147465218 to 2128712446`. The values of X should fall (in most cases) within the union of the FirstX to LastX ranges defined by the rows of the table.

Comment: And what data do you fetch from the rows that correspond to the conditions? At least what kind of data and what datatypes? What processing do you do with it?

Comment: _The table [...] never changes once initialized._... so it is possible for you to create another column and populate it one time, right?

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution that relies on properties of the data in the table. I would rather have a more general solution that doesn't depend on the current data, but for the time being that's the best I have.

The problem with the original query:

```
SELECT P, Y, Z FROM SomeTable WHERE FirstX <= ? AND LastX >= ? LIMIT 10;
```

is that the execution may require scanning a large percentage of the entries in the `FirstX`,`LastX`,`P` index when the first condition `FirstX <= ?` is satisfied by a large percentage of the rows.

What I did to reduce the execution time is observe that `LastX-FirstX` is relatively small.

I ran the query:

```
SELECT MAX(LastX-FirstX) FROM SomeTable;
```

and got `4200000`.

This means that `FirstX >= LastX – 4200000` for all the rows in the table.

So in order to satisfy `LastX >= ?`, we must also satisfy `FirstX >= ? – 4200000`.

So we can add a condition to the query as follows:

```
SELECT P, Y, Z FROM SomeTable WHERE FirstX <= ? AND FirstX >= ? - 4200000 AND LastX >= ? LIMIT 10;
```

In the example I tested in the question, the number of index entries processed was reduced from `2104820` to `18` and the running time was reduced from **0.563 seconds** to **0.0003 seconds**.

I tested the new query with the same `120000` values of `X`. The output was identical to the old query. The time went down from  over **10 hours** to **5.5 minutes**, which is over **100 times faster**.

Comment: Similar improvement on a different set of values??

Comment: No, not similar to mine.  What is the range of values in the table?  Will the `4200000` stay constant, or will it change as new data is inserted?

Comment: You can define an indexed virtual column like `RangeX INT AS (LastX - FirstX)`. Then you can replace the hardcoded value `4200000` with `(SELECT MAX(RangeX) FROM SomeTable)`.

Comment: @RickJames Well, the table remains constant until we import a new version of it into our DB (our application never updates the table), so I can set the `4200000` constant as a configuration parameter.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that would have been useful if the table was updated by our application. Since it is not, there is no problem with defining that constant as a configuration parameter.

Comment: In reloading the table, use `RENAME TABLE` to avoid any downtime.

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE col1 < ... AND ... < col2` is virtually impossible to optimize.

Any useful query will involve a "range" on either col1 or col2.  Two ranges (on two different columns) cannot be used in a single `INDEX`.

Therefore, any index you try has the risk of checking a lot of the table:
`INDEX(col1, ...)` will scan from the start to where `col1` hits `...`.  Similarly for `col2` and scanning until the end.

To add to your woes, the ranges are overlapping.  So, you can't pull a fast one and add `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` to stop quickly.  And if you say `LIMIT 10`, but there are only 9, it won't stop until the start/end of the table.

One simple thing you can do (but it won't speed things up by much) is to swap the `PRIMARY KEY` and the `UNIQUE`.  This could help because InnoDB "clusters" the PK with the data.

If the ranges did not overlap, I would point you at http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges .

So, what can be done??  How "even" and "small" are the ranges?  If they are reasonably 'nice', then the following would take some code, but should be a lot faster.  (In your example, `100000     500000` is pretty ugly, as you will see in a minute.)

Define buckets to be, say, floor(number/100).  Then build a table that correlates buckets and ranges.  Samples:

```
FirstX  LastX  Bucket
123411  123488  1234
222222  222444  2222
222222  222444  2223
222222  222444  2224
222411  222477  2224
```

Notice how some ranges 'belong' to multiple buckets.

Then, the search is first on the bucket(s) in the query, then on the details.  Looking for X=222433 would find two rows with bucket=2224, then decide that both are OK.  But for X=222466, two rows have the bucket, but only one matches with firstX *and* lastX.

```
WHERE bucket = FLOOR(X/100)
  AND firstX <= X
  AND X <= lastX
```

with

```
INDEX(bucket, firstX)
```

But... with `100000     500000`, there would be 4001 rows because this range is in that many 'buckets'.

**Plan B** (to tackle the wide ranges)

Segregate the ranges into wide and narrow.  Do the wide ranges by a simple table scan, do the narrow ranges via my bucket method.  `UNION ALL` the results together.  Hopefully the "wide" table would much smaller than the "narrow" table.

Comment: Nice idea, but the largest difference between FirstX and LastX in my table is 4200000, so that would require many rows for a single range.

Comment: OK, I added a kludge to handle large differences.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another index on LastX.

The unique index FirstLastXPriority_Index (FirstX,LastX,P) represents the **concatenation** of these values, so it will be useless with the 'AND LastX >= ?' part of your WHERE clause.

Comment: I added the second index and now it only uses the second index (on the LastX column). Shouldn't it be using both? And as for the running time, it is faster than the original (for the single query I just tested), but still slow - 0.2 seconds.

Comment: MySQL essentially never uses two indexes at once.  And I don't see that it would even consider it here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way to make the query fast is to reduce the number of fetched and compared fields. Here is the idea.

We can declare a new indexed field (for instance UNSIGNED BIGINT) and store both values FistX and LastX in it using an offset for one of the fields.

For example:

```
FirstX     LastX      CombinedX
100000     500000     100000500000
150000     220000     150000220000
180000     190000     180000190000
550000     660000     550000660000   
70000      90000      070000090000 
75         85         000075000085
```

an alternative is to declare the field as `DECIMAL` and store FirstX + LastX / MAX(LastX) in it.
Later look for the values satisfying the conditions comparing the values with a single field CombinedX.

**APPENDED**

And then you can fetch the rows checking only one field:
by something like where param1=160000

```
SELECT * FROM new_table 
WHERE
(CombinedX <= 160000*1000000) AND
(CombinedX % 1000000 >= 160000);
```

Here I assume that for all FistX < LastX. Of course, you can calculate the param1*offset in advance and store it in a variable against which the further comparisons will be done. Of course, you can consider not decimal offsets but bitwise shifts instead. Decimal offsets were chosen as they are easier to read by a human to show in the sample.

Comment: How would the query look like using your suggested CombinedX column or the DECIMAL column?

Comment: @Eran I appended the answer.

Comment: There is only one parameter in my original query. I need to find the rows that satisfy FirstX <= x AND LastX >= x, so I'm not sure what the two parameters in your example (`param1=100000 and param2=120000`) are referring to.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Really - not a little bit.

Comment: An interesting idea, but I'm not sure how well the index will perform for `CombinedX % 1000000 >= 160000`, since that's equivalent to `(CombinedX >= 160000 AND CombinedX < 1000000) OR (CombinedX >= 1160000 AND CombinedX < 2000000) OR ...`, which searches 1000000 different ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Eran, I believe the solution you found youself **is** the best in terms of minimum costs. It is normal to take into account distribution properties of the data in the DB during optimization process. Moreover, in large systems, it is usually impossible to achieve satisfactory performance, if the nature of the data is not taken into account.

However, this solution also has drawbacks. And the need to change the configuration parameter with every data change is the least. More important may be the following. Let's suppose that one day a very large range appears in the table. For example, let its length cover half of all possible values. I do not know the nature of ​​your data, so I can not definitely know if such a range can ever appear or not, so this is just an assumption. From the point of view to the result, it's okay. It just means that about every second query will now return one more record. But even just one such interval will completely kill your optimization, because the condition `FirstX <=? AND FirstX> =? - [MAX (LastX-FirstX)]` will no longer effectively cut off enough records.

Therefore, if you do not have assurance if too long ranges will ever come, I would suggest you to keep the same idea, but take it from other side.
I propose, when loading new data to the table, break all long ranges into smaller with a length not exceeding a certain value. You wrote that `The important columns of this table are FirstX, LastX, Y, Z and P`. So you can once choose some number N, and every time loading data to the table, if found the range with LastX-FirstX > N, to replace it with several rows:

```
FirstX; FirstX + N
FirstX + N; FirstX + 2N
...
FirstX + kN; LastX
```

and for the each row, keep the same values ​​of Y, Z and P.

For the data prepared that way, your query will always be the same:

```
SELECT P, Y, Z FROM SomeTable WHERE FirstX <=? AND FirstX> =? - N AND LastX> =?
```

and will always be equally effective.

Now, how to choose the best value for N? I would take some experiments with different values and see what would be better. And it is possible for the optimum to be less than the current maximum length of the interval 4200000. At first it could surprise one, because the lessening of N is surely followed by growth of the table so it can become much larger than 4.3 million. But in fact, the huge size of the table is not a problem, when your query uses the index well enough. And in this case with lessening of N, the index will be used more and more efficiently.

Comment: That's a good idea, and if we ever get a table with a too large `MAX (LastX-FirstX)`, I'll definitely consider splitting the rows of the table in this manner. For the time being, I'm satisfied with the performance of my current solution, so I don't see the need to split the rows for the current data. +1

Answer (score 1):

Indexes will not help you in this scenario, except for a small percentage of all possible values of *X*.

Lets say for example that:

- FirstX contains values from 1 to 1000 evenly distributed
- LastX contains values from 1 to 1042 evenly distributed

And you have following indexes:

1. `FirstX, LastX, <covering columns>`
2. `LastX, FirstX, <covering columns>`

Now:

- If X is 50 the clause `FirstX <= 50` matches approximately 5% rows while `LastX >= 50` matches approximately 95% rows. MySQL will use the first index.
- If X is 990 the clause `FirstX <= 990` matches approximately 99% rows while `LastX >= 990` matches approximately 5% rows. MySQL will use the second index.
- Any X between these two will cause MySQL to not use either index (I don't know the exact threshold but 5% worked in my tests). Even if MySQL uses the index, there are just too many matches and the index will most likely be used for covering instead of seeking.

Your solution is the best. What you are doing is defining upper and lower bound of "range" search:

```
WHERE FirstX <= 500      -- 500 is the middle (worst case) value
AND   FirstX >= 500 - 42 -- range matches approximately 4.3% rows
AND   ...
```

In theory, this should work even if you search FirstX for values in the middle. Having said that, you got lucky with *4200000* value; possibly because the maximum difference between first and last is a smaller percentage.

---

If it helps, you can do the following after loading the data:

```
ALTER TABLE testdata ADD COLUMN delta INT NOT NULL;
UPDATE testdata SET delta = LastX - FirstX;
ALTER TABLE testdata ADD INDEX delta (delta);
```

This makes selecting `MAX(LastX - FirstX)` easier.

---

I tested MySQL SPATIAL INDEXES which could be used in this scenario. Unfortunately I found that spatial indexes were slower and have many constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Idea #2**

Do you have control over the Java app?  Because, honestly, 0.3 seconds for an index scan is *not* bad.  Your problem is that you're trying to get a query, run 120,000 times, to have a reasonable end time.

If you *do* have control over the Java app, you could either have it submit *all* the X values at once - and let SQL not have to do an index scan 120k times.  Or you could even just program the logic on the Java side, since it would be relatively easy to optimize.

**Original Idea:**

Have you tried creating a Multiple-Column index?

The problem with having multiple indexes is that each index is only going to narrow it down to ~50% of the records - it has to then match those ~2 million rows of Index A against ~2 million rows of Index B.

Instead, if you get both columns in the same index, the SQL engine can first do a Seek operation to get to the start of the records, and then do a single Index Scan to get the list of records it needs.  No matching one index against another.

I'd suggest *not* making this the Clustered Index, though.  The reason for that?  You're not expecting many results, so matching the Index Scan's results against the table isn't going to be time consuming.  Instead, you want to make the Index as small as possible, so that the Index Scan goes as fast as possible.  Clustered Indexes *are* the table - so a Clustered Index is going to have the same Scan speed as the table itself.  Along the same lines, you probably don't want any other fields other than FirstX and LastX in your index - make that Index as tiny as you can, so that the scan flies along.

Finally, like you're doing now, you're going to need to clue the engine in that you're not expecting a large set of data back from the search - you want to make sure it's using that compact Index for its scan (instead of it saying, "Eh, I'd be better off just doing a full table scan.)

Comment: Unless I don't understand what you mean by "Multiple-Column index", my index already has multiple columns - `UNIQUE KEY FirstLastXPriority_Index (FirstX,LastX,P)`. How should I change it?

Comment: Ah - missed that.  In that case, you might try removing P from the index.  Keep in mind, you're having to do a partial index scan no matter how you structure the query, so you want the index as small as possible.  Removing P shrinks the index by 33%, reducing the scan time by 33%.  If you're only having it look up a few records from the main table, it'll probably be faster without the P in the index.  Anyway, looking over the question again, I think I might reply with another answer along a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to partition the table by different ranges then only querying stuff that fit into a range hence making the amount it needs to check much smaller. This might not work since the java may be slower. But it might put less stress on the database. 
There might be a way also to not Query the database so many times and have a more inclusive SQL(you might be able to send a list of values and have the sql send it to a different table).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you got the execution time down to 0.1 seconds. Would the resulting 3 hours, twenty minutes be acceptable?

The simple fact is that thousands of calls to the same query is incredibly inefficient. Quite aside from what the database has to endure, there is network traffic to think of, disk seek times and all kinds of processing overhead.

Supposing that you don't already have the 120,000 values for `x` in a table, that's where I would start. I would insert them into a table in batches of 500 or so at a time:

```
insert into xvalues (x)
select 14 union all
select 18 union all
select 42 /* and so on */
```

Then, change your query to join to `xvalues`.

I reckon that optimisation alone will get your run-time down to minutes or seconds instead of hours (based on many such optimisations I have done through the years).

It also opens up the door for further optimisations. If the `x` values are likely to have at least some duplicates (say, at least 20% of values occur more than once) it may be worth investigating a solution where you only run the query for unique values and do the insert into `SomeTable` for every `x` with the matching value.

As a rule: anything you can do in bulk is likely to exponentially outperform anything you do row by row.

**PS:**

You referred to a query, but a stored procedure can also work with an input table. In some RDBMSs you can pass a table as parameter. I don't think that works in MySQL, but you can create a temporary table that the calling code fills in and the stored procedure joins to. Or a permanent table used in the same way. The major drawback of not using a temp table, is that you may need to concern yourself with session management or discarding stale data. Only you will know if that is applicable to your case.

Comment: The 120000 values of x were just a sample of inputs on which I tested my query. The actual possible unique values of x can be many more than 120000 (the limit is 2^32). I run the query when an input of x arrives to my application, so I can't group the queries, and I don't know in advance all the possible values of x. I can cache the values that I get in a table (in which case I won't need the original query - I'll simply store for each value of x the corresponding values of y and z), but I still have to support new values of x.

Comment: As for `Suppose you got the execution time down to 0.1 seconds. Would the resulting 3 hours, twenty minutes be acceptable?` - no it wouldn't, since, as you can read in the answer I posted, I already have a workaround that results in 5.5 minutes, so any better solution must have similar performance.

Comment: If you're running the query as values arrive (I must have missed that in your question), then at first glance it's fine to run the query separately for each. But *only* if the 10 hours is then actually a smaller component of the total run-time. If the values arrive very rapidly, you may still benefit from batching them up. Then you don't run it once for 120K records, but once every minute, or whatever a suitable interval is. The point is set-based processing is exponentially faster as a general rule, not just based on your present data set.

Answer (score 0):

So, I dont have enough data to be sure of the run time.  This will only work if column P is unique?  In order to get two indexes working, I created two indexes and the following query...

```
Index A - FirstX, P, Y, Z
Index B - P, LastX
```

This is the query

```
select A.P, A.Y, A.Z 
from 
    (select P, Y, Z from asdf A where A.firstx <= 185000 ) A
    join 
    (select P from asdf A where A.LastX >= 185000 ) B
    ON A.P = B.P
```

For some reason this seemed faster than

```
select A.P, A.Y, A.Z 
from asdf A join asdf B on A.P = B.P
where A.firstx <= 185000 and B.LastX >= 185000
```

Comment: There is a unique column `PrimaryKeyCol` (not P) perhaps play with the primary key, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16667b/3 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c089a/5

Comment: believe it or not I never saw sqlfiddle before LOL!  I will experiment.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize this query:

SELECT P, Y, Z FROM SomeTable WHERE FirstX <= ? AND LastX >= ? LIMIT 10;

Here's 2 resources you can use:

- descending indexes
- spatial indexes

Descending indexes:

One option is to use an index that is descending on FirstX and ascending on LastX.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html

something like:

CREATE INDEX SomeIndex on SomeTable (FirstX DESC, LastX);

Conversely, you could create instead the index (LastX, FirstX DESC).

Spatial indexes:

Another option is to use a SPATIAL INDEX with (FirstX, LastX). If you think of FirstX and LastX as 2D spatial coordinates, then your search what it does is select the points in a contiguous geographic area delimited by the lines FirstX<=LastX, FirstX>=0, LastX>=X.

Here's a link on spatial indexes (not specific to MySQL, but with drawings):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview

Comment: In theory, descending index will not help, it is only useful if you are ordering by that column desc. The spatial index is a good suggestion, but works only on MySQL MyISAM tables.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to precalculate the solutions, if that number isn't too big.

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTableLookUp (
    X INT NOT NULL
    PrimaryKeyCol BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(X, PrimaryKeyCol)
);
```

And now you just pre-populate your constant table.

```
INSERT INTO SomeTableLookUp
SELECT X, PrimaryKeyCol
FROM SomeTable
JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT X FROM SomeTable 
) XS
WHERE XS.X BETWEEN StartX AND EndX
```

And now you can SELECT your answers directly.

```
SELECT SomeTable.*
FROM SomeTableLookup
JOIN SomeTable
ON SomeTableLookup.PrimaryKeyCol = SomeTable.PrimaryKeyCol
WHERE SomeTableLookup = ?
LIMIT 10
```