# Efficient WHERE clause to check value BETWEEN minumim and NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that returns price levels based on the duration of a rental. The table has columns:

```
ProductID (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER), MinDuration(INT), MaxDuration(INT), Price (DECIMAL(10, 4)
```

A simplified version of the query I currently use is :

```
SELECT Price
FROM RentalPrices
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
  AND @Duration BETWEEN MinDuration AND MaxDuration;
```

Table example

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|              ProductID               | MinDuration | MaxDuration | Price |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| e93d19e1-142f-41cc-8f39-9cf7607717ac |           0 | 3           |    25 |
| e93d19e1-142f-41cc-8f39-9cf7607717ac |           4 | 7           |    50 |
| e93d19e1-142f-41cc-8f39-9cf7607717ac |           8 | 14          |   100 |
| e93d19e1-142f-41cc-8f39-9cf7607717ac |          15 | 30          |   200 |
| e93d19e1-142f-41cc-8f39-9cf7607717ac |          31 | NULL        |   500 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

My issue is a value greater or equal to 31 will not find that last row, the open ended maximum, is there a good, simple way to handle this? I know some options that would probably work, but am not sure on what is best.

- `BETWEEN MinDuration AND ISNULL(MaxDuration,2147483647)`
- `@Duration >= MinDuration AND (@Duration <= MaxDuration OR MaxDuration IS NULL)`

In particular the goal is efficiency over the greatest number of cases, it will be rare that we end up hitting that last value (in the real table it's not one month but could be anywhere from six months and up, depending on what product is being rented), so the most efficient solution for where duration is between the two values, while still handling the case where the upper limit is null, with okay efficiency, is the goal.

Comment: Your `ISNULL` seems like a reasonable solution as does your ` AND ( OR )`. What is your concern?

Comment: What is wrong with 2nd option?

Comment: The first option uses a trick. the second option is explicit and straight.

Comment: Efficiency mostly. 2147483647 is due to the column datatype being int. I figured one of those two would be what I have to end up using, and there is of course a risk of overlap with bad data.

Comment: Can you update the value of `MaxDuration` in the `RentalPrices` table assigning `2147483647` where the current value is `null`? That would make querying the table more straight forward.

Comment: @Igor I would want to avoid that for reporting purposes, The end users would probably question such an odd number in their price range printouts, a blank maximum is easier to understand as unlimited than an arbitrary huge number.

Comment: Another option `BETWEEN MinDuration AND ISNULL(MaxDuration,MinDuration)`

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir, but that would be the same as `= MinDuration` where MaxDuration IS NULL, so in the example table 32 returns no price.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir That wouldn't work. `BETWEEN MinDuration AND ISNULL(MaxDuration,@duration)` would though.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, be advised that `WHERE @variable BETWEEN col1 and col2` queries are [usually difficult to optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47798532/87015).

Comment: @SalmanA I can't think of any other system for a range, other than using >= AND <=, and I have to believe between is a better solution, or else why impliment it at all?

Comment: BETWEEN is just syntax sugar for that. It doesn't provide any performance advantages or disadvantages. but hopefully your equality predicate on ProductId is quite selective and filters things down to a smallish number of rows?

Comment: @MartinSmith There will only be about a dozen to 18ish rows matching the ProductID, each with different date ranges (1 day, 2 days, 3 days , 1 week, 2 weeks etc)

Comment: Trying to optimise the range seek part probably isn't a massive priority then.

Comment: @MartinSmith not huge, but optimizing everything is always a goal. Right now we only have one tenant on the system that will be using rentals, everyone else is pure sales, but this query will be made per product, per rental contract, possibly a few times as they adjust dates, will even have to be made when they are looking for quotes, small improvements on a query run hundreds of times a day add up.

Comment: Hundreds of times a day is nothing. you could maybe shave a ms or two off the average query execution and that's still less than a second per week.

Comment: @MartinSmith For one query, for one tenant, of the hundreds of other instances of DB access, it does all add up. If I can optimise even a small query, I should. The same query is run for other tenants, against their salesprice table, without the between clause.

Comment: @Andrew see linked question which discusses optimization. `@x BETWEEN col1 AND col2` is same as writing `col1 <= @x and col2 >= @x` and index (seek) cannot be used. Index would help if the condition was `@x <= col and @y >= col`.

Comment: @SalmanA an index seek can be used but on average it will only discard half the range. Gordon's edited answer should allow an efficient single row seek though. Although the difference between seeking 9 rows and 1 will not be massive,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient method is probably to ignore `maxduration`!

```
SELECT TOP (1) Price
FROM ?
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID AND MinDuration <= @Duration
ORDER BY MinDuration DESC;
```

This can make use of an index on `(ProductId, MinDuration)`.

As for your question itself.  I would vote for storing the maximum value in the table and not using `NULL` for that purpose.  Not the most aesthetic solution but it simplifies the coding.  The choice between the two methods you propose is really about aesthetics (although I would use the ANSI standard `COALESCE()`).

Comment: Ordering needs to be DESC?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. If the duration passed is 6 then the first row shouldn't be returned as the max duration of that is 3 so this is not suitable for someone looking for a 6 day rental.

Comment: @andrew In your example, if you have `@duration` of 20, then you want the row with 15->30?  As all the records with lower durations are also returned, you want the record with the Highest MinDuration that's lower than your search variable?

Comment: @MatBailie Single row return, actually saclar value return since I only select one column on the row here.

Comment: @andrew In this answer the where clause only filters by min duration.  The where clause acquires all rows where the MinDuration is less than or equal to your variable. Then those rows are ordered, and the first (top 1) row actually returned. That one row should have the highest MinDuration of the rows found by the where clause.  Thus they should be ordered descending, to ensure the highest matching value is first. (Ordering ascending will always return the 0-3 row...)

Comment: This does not really answer the question in general, it only works for the specific case where someone is interested in probing price for a particular product. It won't work for example when there is no `WHERE Product = @ProductID`. (I think) the question is about generic way to query values between x and infinity.

Comment: @MatBailie I believe you're right. For simple mistakes like this where it's clear what the answerer meant, it's okay to just edit. I'd already done the same when I noticed that the comparison was the wrong way around.

Comment: I think this will return the first row every time

Comment: After the edit it will work, as long as the ranges in the table are non overlapping. So there is only one applicable rental offer for a ProductId/duration.

Comment: @MartinSmith  I tested the edit and it does not work for me

Comment: The addition of Desc to the ORDER BY.

Comment: @MartinSmith That edit did not show up for me.  I had to refresh.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most efficient but I think is clean

```
SELECT Price
FROM RentalPrices
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
AND @Duration BETWEEN MinDuration AND isnull(MaxDuration, @Duration);
```

Consider a clustered PK on ProductID, Price

```
declare @rental table (id int not null, minDuration int not null, maxDuration int, price int not null);
insert into @rental (id, minDuration, maxDuration, price) values 
         (1, 0, 3, 25)
       , (1, 4, 7, 50)  
       , (1, 8, 14, 100)
       , (1, 15, 30, 200)
       , (1, 31, null, 500);

declare @id int = 1;
declare @duration int = 15;

select id, minDuration, maxDuration, price 
  from @rental
 order by id, MinDuration;

SELECT Price, @duration, minDuration, maxDuration
  FROM @rental
 WHERE id = @id
   AND @duration BETWEEN minDuration AND isnull(maxDuration, @Duration)
 order by id, minDuration;
```

Comment: This is same as `MinDuration <= @Duration ...`, same as the other answer but does not require TOP/ORDER BY.

Comment: Won't `ISNULL(MaxDuration, @Duration)` always match, causing an extra result when @Duration falls into a lesser bracket? Certainly the larger row could be ignored then, or we could `SELECT TOP 1` which would return only the first match anyways in the order, but it is a concern with the response as written, requiring code to work around it on the server.